# Bootstrap Datepicker - setStartDate issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to change the starting date of a bootstrap datepicker input field.

I have 2 fields both are datepickers.

- actie_begin
- actie_end

When I **change *actie_begin*** I want the **startDate of** ***actie_end*** to be set to the value of actie_start.

here's the code I wrote

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".actie_begin").datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startView: 'month',
        minView: 'month',
        autoclose: true,
        startDate:'-0d'
    });

    $("#actie_end").datetimepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        startView: 'month',
        minView: 'month',
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: '-0d'
    });


    $( ".datepicker" ).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $('#actie_end').datepicker('setStartDate', $("#actie_begin").val());
    });
</script>
```

The datepickers work, but when I try change the date on *actie_begin* I receive this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

The values get set and I can pick the dates, but the startDate on *actie_end* does not work.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check the format of  $("#actie_begin").val(). The format should match

Comment: The problem which I can clearly see is u r using `datepicker` instead of `datetimepicker` in    `$('#actie_end').datepicker('setStartDate', $("#actie_begin").val());` this line